# Stack Exchange 'answers' link points to questions

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, hyperlinks

The 'answers' link on this page: https://stackexchange.com/

[image: Answers links screenshot]

is pointing to the same page as the 'n million questions' link. Shouldn't this link point to recently answered questions instead? (if such a page exists)

Comment: Not necessarily most recent, but true, it should only show *answered* ones.

Comment: This will be a fitting link: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=is%3aanswer

Comment: Oh wait... it's about the **overall network questions**, not Stack Overflow. Well, we have only "Hot Questions", no hot answers to it's quite a problem.